# Is a specific @RequestMapping always called in favour of a variable @RequestMapping in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping

Let's assume following controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/info")
  public InfoModel getInfo(){ 
    ... 
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/{resourceId}")
  public ResourceModel getResource(@PathVariable("resourceId") String resourceId){
    ...
  }
}
```

The question is: Which method will be invoked when curling `GET /info`.

In all my tests `getInfo` was called which seems to be clear.

But I'm not 100% sure if this is just a lucky race condition or if it is specified that a static path has a higher precedence than a variable path.

Even after some research I couldn't find the specification for this case, only some pretty old (and probably outdated) blog posts.

I'm using SpringBoot 2.0.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not a lucky race condition. The pattern with no path variables will always take precedence.

Please refer to the Spring MVC documentation that explains everything in detail [Request Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) under `Pattern Comparison`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the path specified at class level (@RequestMapping("/home") as per below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class MyController {

      @RequestMapping(method = GET, path = "/info")
      public InfoModel getInfo(){ 
        ... 
      }
}
```

then you would have to curl GET /home/info. All urls path are defined/decided by you.